# How to record keyboard macro?

Tags: windows-10, macros, rename, filenames

I have a task to rename a lot of photos that had naming corruption and I have to rename each photo a lone which is a lot of work.

I thought why won't there be a solution to record all the process of selecting a photo, then choose rename, then paste the required name and choose YES for the warning that the file could be unusable like this one:

[image]

and another yes for numbering duplicate naming like:

[image]

How to record all these steps with just selecting all the photos, drag them into a cmd program or right click and choose the recorded macro ?

---

Edit:

Here's an example of the problem in my folders.

[image]

The extension is developed in a way that it is so difficult to change it by ordinary windows rename or even by cmd special commands.

Comment: if you use cmd then just rename the file in command line. There won't be any message boxes like that

Comment: Yeah I tried that it didn't work. My naming corruption is so difficult to solve !! Let me update my post.

Comment: use powershell's rename. It accepts any regexes or any code blocks to do custom renaming

Comment: OK, could you point me to a link that has the commands I need for this operation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just need the files to have the correct extension and don't care very much about the filenames, in that case the following PowerShell command should do:

Just open PowerShell and paste the following command. You might need to correct the path.

```
Get-ChildItem "I:\media & personal\personal pictures_need_rename\camera" | foreach { mv $_.FullName "$($_.FullName).JPG"}
```

What this does is it adds ".jpg" to each and every file in the specified folder. For example, `IMG_2.J04` becomes `IMG_2.J04.JPG`

Comment: Thank you so much man :))

Answer (score 2):

Though it won't record macros, if you wish to use a graphical interface to rename files in bulk, this sounds possibly like a job for [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/). It's free for personal use and has quite a few options to manipulate file names.

For instance, assuming you wanted to change ex.:

```
IMG_2.J01
IMG_2.J02
IMG_2.J03
etc.
```

to ex.:

```
Vacation - 1.jpg
Vacation - 2.jpg
Vacation - 3.jpg
etc.
```

You could select the original images in the main BRU window (i.e. with the Left Mouse Button and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, as normal) and could adjust/apply the BRU `Remove (5)`, `Add (7)`, `Numbering (10)` and `Extension (11)` filters:

*ex. Bulk Rename Utility*

[image: Bulk Rename Utility - Screenshot]

After selecting the `Rename` button in the lower right of the BRU interface, the new file names (previewed/updated in real time in green) would be applied to the files.

Comment: Thanks ! I actually tried to use this program before but I think I didn't know how to use it.

Comment: You're welcome. =) Sometimes the best solutions are the simplest.